# Kotlin Compiler Error with super.onCreate in a Class Implementing DefaultLifecycleObserver

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm encountering a compiler error in Kotlin with the following code:

```
class XXXApplication : MultiDexApplication(), DefaultLifecycleObserver {
    override fun onResume(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        super.onResume(owner)
    }

    override fun onPause(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        super.onPause(owner)
    }

    companion object {
        lateinit var instance: XXXApplication private set
    }

    private lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        instance = this

        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)

        initLifecycleObserver()
    }

    private fun initLifecycleObserver() {
        val lifecycle: Lifecycle = ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle
        lifecycle.removeObserver(this)
        lifecycle.addObserver(this)
    }

    fun getSharedPreferences(): SharedPreferences {
        return sharedPreferences
    }
}
```

The Kotlin compiler complains about the line `super.onCreate()` with the following error message:

```
Many supertypes available, please specify the one you mean in angle brackets, e.g., 'super<Foo>'
```

`MultiDexApplication` has an `onCreate()` method,

and `DefaultLifecycleObserver` has an `onCreate(owner: LifecycleOwner)` method.

So, when `XXXApplication` calls super.`onCreate()`, it seems obvious that `XXXApplication` is referring to `MultiDexApplication`'s `onCreate()` method, which does not have any parameters.

Why is the Kotlin compiler raising this error?

Comment: Because of how the compiler is implemented. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-39599/Super-calls-resolution-doesnt-consider-signatures-when-reporting-ambiguity

Answer (score 0):

Both `MultiDexApplication` and `DefaultLifecycleObserver` have `onCreate` method. From your code I assume you want to call application's `onCreate`, so change this method like this:

```
...
override fun onCreate() {
    super<MultiDexApplication>.onCreate()
...
```

Full code:

```kotlin
class XXXApplication : MultiDexApplication(), DefaultLifecycleObserver {
    override fun onResume(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        super.onResume(owner)
    }

    override fun onPause(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        super.onPause(owner)
    }

    companion object {
        lateinit var instance: XXXApplication private set
    }

    private lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences

    override fun onCreate() {
        super<MultiDexApplication>.onCreate()

        instance = this

        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)

        initLifecycleObserver()
    }

    private fun initLifecycleObserver() {
        val lifecycle: Lifecycle = ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle
        lifecycle.removeObserver(this)
        lifecycle.addObserver(this)
    }

    fun getSharedPreferences(): SharedPreferences {
        return sharedPreferences
    }
}
```